# Why are there only arm build for libc while there are specifically armv7a and armeabi build for libstdc++?

Tags: android-ndk

My understanding of arm (under the context of cross-compilation) is a general name for describing a series of ABIs. It can be further divided into to armeabi, armeabi-v7a, armeabi-v8a...etc.

1. I assumed the general "arm" means the oldest version (i.e. "armeabi") which is backward-compatible with all newer versions (e.g. armeabi-v7a, armeabi-v8a). Is this assumption correct?
2. Why is there only arm build for libc while there are specific armeabi and armeabi-v7a for libstdc++?

Comment: The arm64-v8a libraries are found under `arch-arm64`. As for the `arch-arm` directory, it contains armeabi (v5te) libraries for platform-19 and below, and armeabi-v7a libraries for platform-21 and above.

Comment: @Michael So it means there is a default ABI for each version of Android API if I get it correctly?

Comment: Well, for 32-bit ARM ABIs there appears to be a distinction based on which `APP_PLATFORM` you build for. Note that armeabi is deprecated in NDK r16 and will be removed in r17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**libc.so** that is part of NDK is only a stub, used to help to link your binaries. The actual library is preinstalled on the device. On the other hand, the STL library is packaged with your APK - whether linked statically or as a separate shared lib.